# For loop not working without range() " string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, for-loop

`i` is a string, so how can I make this work?

How can I use `i` as index?

```
for i in s[1:]:
    if s[i] <= s[i-1]:
        temp += s[i]
    else:
        subs.append(temp)
        temp = ''
```

I've tried to use

```
for i in s[1:]:
    if s.index(i) >= s.index(i-1):
        temp += s[i]
    else:
        subs.append(temp)
        temp = ''
```

And I get

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `i` is a *character* in `s`, not an index.

Comment: damn... it's true but why does it work with range?

Comment: @JEdward Because range returns numbers in a range.

Comment: @Edward: because `range()` produces a sequence of integers, not characters.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax you are using is corresponding to string iteration (see http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html) so the `i` will iterate on the different characters of the string on note on their indices:

```
>>> for i in "hello"[1:]:
...   print i
... 
e
l
l
o
```

<del>in the initial faulty loop, note that access to respectively `s[i+1]` or `s[i-1]` are incorrect when `i` is pointing to respectively last and first character of the string.</del> (question modified)

To iterate on the indices, use xrange (for instance between second and the one before the last character):

```
s='hello'
for i in xrange(1,len(s)-1):
   print i,s[i]
```

Generates:

```
e
l
l
```

Comment: This explains why he's getting an error, it doesn't explain how to fix it.

Comment: @JEdward you have modified the question - you do need to use range, or better xrange - but the simplest is that you tell us what you are trying to do

Answer (score -1):

When you iterate through a string using "for i in s[1:]", it will assign i the value of each character in the string. You may want to use the iterator "enumerate" in the loop instead. It will assign a sequential numeric value to every byte in the string, while assigning s[i] to v.

```
for i, v in enumerate(s):
    if v <= s[i-1]:
        temp += v
    else:
        stubs.append(temp)
        temp = ''
```

Comment: You need to check for `i > 0`, so you don't get an index error.